# Save on off switch state when navigating to alternative area in app

Tags: java, html, css, switch-statement, state

I am making an app for iphones and android using a third party app maker, its quite simple but I am having issues with one part in particular. In one folder there is an yes no switch, I want to make it so that when the user changes it to yes it will stay that way no matter where they navigate to next. I have the option to use Html CSS and java to do this. below is all the code I have set out so far for the switch but I cant get it to stay on no matter what I am trying.

1) the switch will not remain on yes for all users it will stay in its default option of no until the specific user of the app switches it to yes.

I am not a pro coder I really only know the basics of Html and CSS so any advise and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

essentially I was thinking of using a java cookie method, would this work ?

***UPDATE***:-     http://jsfiddle.net/Lucianlegion/Dp4Tj/100/

```
$(function () {
var data = localStorage.getItem("showning");
if (data !== null) {
    $("input[name='onoffswitch']").attr("checked", "checked");
}
});

$("input[name='onoffswitch']").click(function () {

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem("showning", 1);
} else {
    localStorage.removeItem("showning");
}

});
```

I have managed to get this to work however it doesn't seem to work when I click the button from a mobile phone any idea why ?

Comment: You can use localstorage to store the state.

Comment: is it possible to apply a time stamp for the save if I add a cookie to the local storage ? @sasi

Comment: Actually you don't have to store the cookies into the localstorage. You just have to store the state of the button [ yes/no ], and if you need to store the timestamp then you can take it through code and save it in storage.

Comment: I know this is a bit much to ask so apologize in advance but it there any chance you might be willing to give an example on how that can be done ? @sasi